# Getting RGB value under mouse cursor stuck

Tags: java

im having trouble with this code. I want to be able to move the mouse around and get the pixel value (red,green,blue) matter where the mouse is. Im having trouble using the "getRGB". How would your start it off. Can someone point me to the right direction.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.MouseInfo;
    import java.awt.Point;
    import java.awt.PointerInfo;
    import java.awt.Robot;

   public class PixelColor {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PointerInfo pointer;
    pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point coord = pointer.getLocation();

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(2000);


    int red = getred();
    int green= getgreen();
    int blue= getblue();
    int color = new Color (red,green,blue).getRGB();

    while(true) {
        coord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();  
        color = getred();

        {
    System.out.println(getRGB());




        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the color outside of your java app?

Comment: Does your code compile? Does it run? Any errors? What problems are you having? Please take a little time to describe the details or your problem since this information will greatly improve the help we can give you.

Comment: You appear to be calling methods that you haven't yet defined.

Comment: How would you define them ?? I'm new to java so yup

Comment: It does compile just nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Look into using Robot's getPixelColor method:

```
color = robot.getPixelColor(coord.x, coord.y);
```

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class PixelColor {
   private static final long SLEEP_DELAY = 400L;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Point coord;
      Robot robot = null;

      try {
         robot = new Robot();
      } catch (AWTException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }

      Color color = null;
      while (true) {
         coord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
         color = robot.getPixelColor(coord.x, coord.y);
         System.out.println(color);
         try {
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the pixel color where the mouse pointer is, you have to get the mouse position in every
iteration of the loop, and then use the method `getPixelColor`of robot.

```
while(true) 
{
    pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    coord = pointer.getLocation();
    System.out.print(coord.x + " " + coord.y);
    System.out.println(" color: " + robot.getPixelColor(coord.x, coord.y).getRed() +                                             
                           ", " + robot.getPixelColor(coord.x, coord.y).getGreen() + 
                ", " + robot.getPixelColor(coord.x, coord.y).getBlue());
}
```